# How do I enable the clickable elements in my modal?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, addeventlistener

I successfully created a script that opens a modal when a user double-clicks anywhere on the body of a document **OF COURSE** apart from the ordinary clickable elements. However, this very same script also disables all the clickable elements in the modal when it opens. This means **NONE** my **addEventListeners** for `click` or `dblclick` on the modal work at all. I can't even close the modal.

Naturally, the desired effect would be to be able to interact with the clickable elements when the modal opens as the modal body has a few buttons & links.

Find below my code:

```
// Creates the modal inside the iframe
const modal = iframe.contentWindow.document.createElement('div');
```

Here is the double-click function that opens the modal

```
const callModal = document.querySelector('body');
callModal.addEventListener('dblclick', (event) => {
  if (!isBodyClickable(event.target)) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Open Modal
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modal.style.transform = 'translateX(0%)';   
  }
});
```

Following is a control function that ensures that **only** none clickable elements open up the modal.

```
function isBodyClickable(element) {
  // Returns true if element is clickable, false otherwise
  const tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
  const clickableTags = ['a', 'abbr', 'audio', 'canvas', 'details', 'iframe', 'img', 'input', 'label', 'map', 'optgroup', 'option', 'select', 'summary', 'textarea', 'video'];

  if (clickableTags.includes(tagName) || element.hasAttribute('tabindex') || element.closest('.modal')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Following is a modal interaction function that doesn't work

```
// Toggle light/dark theme
const toggleThemes = modal.querySelector('.switchTheme');
toggleThemes.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log('You clicked on ThemeToggle')
if (!isModalClickable(event.target)) {
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleTheme();
}
});
```

Can anyone kindly how I can modify the `toggleThemes.addEventListener('click',...` to enable me to interact with the clickable elements in my modal?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to resolve this issue was to modify the 'callModal' event handler to restore all clickable elements on the page after opening up the modal.

Following is my 'callModal' event handler after modification

```
const callModal = document.querySelector('body');
callModal.addEventListener('dblclick', (event) => {
  if (!isBodyClickable(event.target)) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Open Modal
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modal.style.transform = 'translateX(0%)'; 

    //Restore all clickable elements on the page
    document.querySelectorAll('body *').forEach(el => {
      el.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    });


  }
});
```